# Is there a way to store how many times users press a button securely

Tags: security, networking, https, firebase-security

A general question about the concept of request sniffing and re-sending.

Current approach: When user taps the button, they send a request and increment their numPressed field in a database. What stops a malicious user from sniffing this request and sending it on repeat without actually pressing the button.

Current solutions: Having a timestamp since last press to prevent excess requests. Still wouldn't ensure that the button was pressed.

Current stack: flutter, firebase.

Not necessarily interested in the used stack only but interested in this security concept as a whole. Thank you.

Comment: Are nonces generally only used for authentication?

Comment: @Martheen If a fresh nonce comes back with the response, it’s easy to use for an attacker too. It just slows them down insofar as they can only send requests serially, not in parallel.